# stdin: is not a tty when running 'git push' - github over ssh

Tags: ssh, git-lfs

I am using Git on Windows and everything was working fine till recently.

In the last few days I have been getting an error when trying to push my local branch to remote on GitHub. I am connecting to GitHub via SSH. The error that I'm getting is

```
stdin is not a tty
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:xxx/yyy.git'
```

This happens regardless whether I try to push a new branch (without a remote) or an existing one. Both of those commands fail in the same way:

```
git push
git push -u origin tomasz/test
```

all other git commands seem to be working fine, i.e. `git pull`, `fetch` etc.

I have been googling for the last few days but couldn't find anything that would fix it

[image]

Update 1:
I tried one of the solutions proposed by running `pull --rebase ...`, this is the outcome:
[image]

Update:2
Git Trace failed ssh protocol connection gives error
`14:49:50.463468 trace git-lfs: pure SSH protocol connection failed: Unable to negotiate version with remote side (unable to read capabilities): EOF`
[image]

Comment: if you add `--verbose` option, will there be some hints?

Comment: @LeiYang not really, just says `Pushing to github.com:xxx/yyy.git` prior to `stdin` error

Comment: Run with `GIT_TRACE=1` so that you can observe Git running ssh and/or pre-push hooks. I think the error you're getting is coming from one of these. (That is, `GIT_TRACE=1 git push`)

Comment: @torek thanks, I was looking to find a way to get more logs/details. The only suspicious trace that I have found `14:49:50.463468 trace git-lfs: pure SSH protocol connection failed: Unable to negotiate version with remote side (unable to read capabilities): EOF`

Comment: Aha, this is Git-LFS, not Git. You're in the pre-push phase where LFS tries to upload any large files to the server, which happens *before* `git push` begins. (Exactly what's going wrong, I don't know, but you need an LFS debug step, not a Git debug step.)

Comment: thanks, this `GIT_TRACE=1` was exactly what I needed to find out the issue. Like you have said, it was Git-lfs pre-hooks that were changed/corrupted/removed. I have fixed it by running `git lfs update --force` as normal update didn't want to go through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you to @torek who gave me a way to get more detailed debugging logs `GIT_TRACE=1 git push`

This has narrowed down the issue to be from Git-LFS, instead of GIT/Github/GitBash.

I have fixed it by running:
`git lfs update --force` as normal `update` was coming back with conflict errors

Comment: I've been stuck with this error for about an hour. It really did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Reason:
in GitHub, the file is not in the local warehouse.

Solutions:

```
git pull --rebase origin tomasz/test
git push -u origin tomasz/test
```

Comment: unfortunately, this hasn't fixed it. I have updated my post with the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this issue when running a pre-push hook with husky,
and what worked for me was redirecting standard input, output, and error streams
to < /dev/tty
This can sometimes trick applications into behaving as though they're running in a TTY:
The code for my pre-push script is looking like this now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"
yarn test < /dev/tty
```